# Custom activity indicator popup

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, ipad

This may be a simple question but i would like some help to find out how to make it.

I want to make a custom "loading" popup for my ipad app.
Just like this app:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZY31Bn5slv0
you see the black loading popup at +- 30sec,40sec,56sec,...

I remember that i had a sample of this, but can't find it back.

Can someone show me which way to look?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like a `UIView` with curved corners a `UIActivityIndicator` and a `UILabel` saying "loading".

Comment: thanks, the keyword "curved corners" leaded me to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031930/how-is-a-rounded-rect-view-with-transparency-done-on-iphone

Comment: theres an easier way to do it... `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and then you can do `myView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;`

Comment: oké.. didn't knwow that property... But i think using MBProgressHUD is easyer, then you don't have to do the same work twice. Anyway thanks for response!

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html) is exactly what you want.
After adopting this,
in `initWithFrame:` mehode of `Loadingview` create a frame with `CGRectMake(0,0,300,300)`  then make it center `loadingView.center = aSuperView.center;`
and inside the `drawRect:` methode set `ROUND_RECT_CORNER_RADIUS = 20;`

Comment: I already have a look alike: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MBProgressHUD, but you get a vote ;)