# iOS rounded corner UIImage with border

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

Is there a way to make my image appear like this (rounded corners and with a light border).[image]

I'm thinking of creating a white mask that has the middle transparent to place on top, would that work?

Comment: Check this link out - it references UIWebViews but it's the same for UIImageViews - http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/add-rounded-corners-and-border-to-uiwebview.html

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1651383/1615838

Comment: Does any solution worked for you? Please give some feedback, upvote and accept one answer in order to remove it from the Unanswered section.

Answer (score 17):

You can accomplish this, but instead of editing your UIImage, just do this in your UIImageView.

First, add the QuartzCore header

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

And then, edit the properties below, as you wish.

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
imageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to look at the [QuartzCore docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500), specifically the cornerRadius, borderColor and borderWidth properties within CALayer.